# join HTML segments from different origins and load correctly in a browser

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I want to join HTML segments from several different origins and then load the joint one correctly in a browser.

For example, one HTML segment excerpted from `www.1_example.com/1` might contain `<img src='/pic/insects_comp.jpg'>`, and another  HTML segment excerpted from `www.2_example.com/2` might contain `<script src="picturefill.js" async></script>` and `<link href="svg-style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`, the problem is how to handle relative pathnames of external resources, such as JavaScript programs, style sheets, or images, in different HTML segment(from different origins) so that the browser could find the correct address of each and then to render the final HTML document correctly in a browser?

I've thought one method like this :

1. Find all relative pathnames of external resources using regular
   expressions or using `document.images`, `document.scripts`, and
   `document.style​Sheet​Sets`.
2. Replacing the relative pathnames of external resources by their
   URLs.

Any other efficient ways ?

Comment: Couldn't you just use Iframes?

Comment: @dbramwell But how to convert relative pathnames of external resources to their URLs in iframe ?

Comment: Replacing relative URLs with the absolute ones is quite trivial (depending on how you get the htmls) so I'd go with it.

Comment: @wOxxOm but there is actually a need to get the URL of  each external resource in order to render the final HTML document correctly in the browser

Comment: Why "but"? It's a basic requirement, not an optional thing.

Comment: @wOxxOm Sorry for my poor English , I mean if I didn't relative URLs with the absolute ones, then the browser didn't know the actually address of each each external resource.

Comment: I don't understand what we're discussing, sorry.

Comment: Without a real [MCVE](/help/mcve) I can only reiterate my first comment - getting the full URL might be as trivial as using `element.src`.